# How work the session when a user buy a product form a store

Tags: php, mysql, session, paypal

I know about session and using it well. I know to use the session I should put the `session_start()` top of each page that I want to use the `session`. But I found a problem in understanding of an issue.

Consider we have a bank that it called `A` bank and I want use from its payment gateway.Also consider we have a user that its username is `B` and he\she want to buy a product form the store.

At first, when the login operation is successfully, the `login.php` file will get the session from the user and  will save the `$username` value in the `$_SESSION[login_user]` variable.

We know that the  `$_SESSION[login_user]` variable is a global variable. This means that if the username is `B` and login operation is successful as the result the  `$_SESSION[login_user]` will get the `B` value and if we use the  `$_SESSION[login_user]` in each `php` file, the value in the `$_SESSION[login_user]` is `B`.

And then consider the user clicks the buy button and the store redirects the user to the payment gateway and he/she can buy a product successfully.Now the payment gateway sends information about payment to the server. Now the big problem is that in here, the user does not send a request to get the his/her session. In here, the payment gateway from the `A` bank requests and sends information to the store.

Now I want to save the username that has purchased in the database. 
I do not know What do I do. Since there is no a good tutorials about this issue, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

First declare a variable and make it equal your session data like this and put it in your php

```
$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

Then insert into the database with this

```
INSERT INTO database (column_name) VALUES ('$username')";
```

I am not 100% sure about putting the quotes inside the session square brackets, I see you didn't put any in, but I think you need them.

Comment: If I use in `login.php` file the `$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];`  and  now when the user pays successfully, the bank sends to my `check.php` file information about  the authenticity of transaction. **But this time the request is from the bank a not from the user.**  if I use in `check.php` file the same    `$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];` that I used it in `login.php`, are there his/her username in the `$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];` in the `check.php` file still?  This doubt has been created because **the `check.php` gets the request from bank and not from user.**